# Timeout message author using Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord command using `discord.py` where the user can call the command and there would be a 50-50 chance that the author itself would get timed out. Here is what I've written so far, I don't know how to call the timeout part

```
async def zeus(ctx):
  val = 1
  boom = random.randint(1,2)
  if val == boom:
    await #timesout the author/the caller of command for 10 minutes
  else:
    pass
```

EDIT:
I am unaware of how to use Member.timed_out_until for the author themselves.

Comment: You're probably looking for [`Member.timed_out_until`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=timed_out#discord.Member.timed_out_until). You have to pass a datetime and make it timezone aware.

Comment: @EricJin can this work to timeout the author of the message itself? If yes, how would the syntax change

Comment: @Seiden Hi, could you edit your question to include the question you've asked in the comments? I can provide an answer if you do so.

Comment: @EricJin That would check how long the member is timed out for. It wouldn't time the member out

Comment: I think you are able to modify it (also I think `member.edit` allows you to change it)

Comment: @goose.mp4 I've edited the question as you said

Answer (score -1):

This should work (I’ve only tested it in py-cord, but it should work in discord.py)

```
import datetime
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands
import random

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def zeus(ctx):
    boom = random.randint(0, 1) == 0

    if boom:
        await ctx.message.author.timeout_for(datetime.timedelta(seconds=10))

bot.run("TOKEN HERE")
```

Comment: discord.py is currently being maintained and [has this feature](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.timeout).

Comment: Oh, sorry I think at one point it did stop being maintained, and now is again - I will update my answer

Comment: @Jaffa I'm getting the error ```AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'timeout_for'``` I did try using timeout instead of timeout_for but doesn't work

Comment: oh, I think the syntax is a little different for discord.py, try timeout instead of timeout_for @Seiden

Comment: @Jaffa have tried timeout as well, same error

Comment: Try updating it, and if that doesn't work you could try py-cord (which I wrote the code in)

Comment: @Jaffa I've written some other commands as well, would it require me to re-write the whole bot code again?

Comment: I think that the syntax is the same (at lest for older features). You shouldn't have to change much, if at all